# NextJS Dynamic and Static URL in one Level

Tags: next.js, url-routing

Is it possible in NextJS to have a URL like this?

`/items/item-[id]`

or

`/items/items-[page]-[offset]`

What I am doing here is to have as much as the fewest possible levels as possible. I have tried these both and nothing works. I do not want to have a URL with `/items/item/[id]` or `/items/items/[page]/[offset]`. I am trying to do this for both SEO and human-readability reasons.

Is there any example or documentation that points that this is possible or not possible?

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense from a SEO or human readable standpoint.  There is a reason almost all websites follow the url schema you are trying to avoid.  Your URLs should be items [item-id]/[item-slug] or items/[item-slug],  & /items?page=1&offset=10.   Your page number should be a get param. You will eventually end up with not found or linking to a page where the content no longer lives if it's hardcoded and it which will hurt SEO.   If you insist, you can do /items/[page] and in your static routes prefix each URL with items-.

Comment: I think my example didn't really explain why I want everything on the same level. The parameters I have are for products, example, color, size, brand and probably five more. If I am going to implement this in nextjs, it would be /brand/color/size/other1/other2/other3 five levels of folders with just one file inside of it. Also if I'm going to implement something like this, it would mean that brand is more important than size because it comes ahead of it. That's why I want everything to be in one level because their keywords are of equal importance.

Comment: You can do it like /items/[slug] and then parse and enforce the format of that slug yourself, e.g. in getServerSideProps.  But like @SeanW explained, you'll have to be careful or you could end up with broken links in the long term.

Comment: @JamesArnold You can follow the `/brand/color/size/other1/other2/other3` URL schema and still have everything under a single "level" by using [catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes).

Comment: @juliomalves thanks. yes, this is the one that I am exploring.

Comment: Catch all is what you're going to need.  You have to be deliberate with this approach. You must set your canonical URLs.  The reason IDs are almost always in the URL is so the content after the URL can be misspelled or mistyped and it would still return the correct item. I recommend doing /[brand-slug]/[item-id-or-slug-that-cant-be-updated-once-published]/catchall/whatever/you/want/ & set your canonical to /[brand-slug]/[item-slug-or-id]/ to prevent duplicate content. This also allows you to update the item and not be dependent on any other params or break search engine linked pages.